# Change blur effect style on-the-fly

Tags: ios, swift, uiblureffect

Is it any way to change blur effect style on-the-fly after creating view?

E.g. i've created in Storyboard blur view, but i need to change effect style from .Light to .Dark programmatically.

I can't just re-create view, because I have information in that view and dynamic constraints (constraints change with animations in some situations).

Comment: i know how to add, i need to change effect without recreating view

Comment: The `UIVisualEffectView` properties `effect` and `contentView` are read-only, but you might be able to re-use the `contentView`.

Answer (score 14):

yes, we can change the blur effect style on the fly... here is the code you are looking for....

`MyView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
MyView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
MyView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)`

Comment: Thank you Fansad for the proper solution.. guys please upvote for this solution.